# If $11|a^{100}+b^{100}+c^{100}$ prove that $11^{100}|a^{100}+b^{100}+c^{100}$ . How can I prove this?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory

If $11|a^{100}+b^{100}+c^{100}$ prove that $11^{100}|a^{100}+b^{100}+c^{100}$

Comment: Pen and paper is a good start

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: show that $x^{100}\equiv 1\pmod{11}$ if $x\not\equiv 0\pmod{11}$. For this, note $x^{100}=(x^{11-1})^{10}$ and recall [Fermat's Little Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). From that and $11|a^{100}+b^{100}+c^{100}$, conclude that $a,b,c\equiv 0\pmod{11}$ and so $a^{100},b^{100},c^{100}\equiv 0\pmod{11^{100}}$.

Answer (score 2):

It's modular arithmetic. You first use Fermat's little theorem;
$$\forall x\neq0 \ [11],\quad x^{10}=1\ [11]$$
So $a^{100}+b^{100}+c^{100} = \#\{x\in \{a,b,c\}|x\neq 0\ [11]\} [11]$, thus $a,b,c$ are multiples of $11$ so $a^{100},b^{100},c^{100}$ are multiples of $11^{100}$.